# Powershell split file name and export to csv

Tags: powershell

I have lot of files in the folder in this nameing format "yyyy-mm-dd_Discription_$Amount.pdf" , how do I make powershell script that creates csv file with three columns (Date , Description and Amount)?

I am able to extract the full file name in the below, but I need help to split and make columns.

```
$Directory = "C:\path to directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach {

    [PSCustomObject]@{                 
        Name = $_.BaseName          
    }
    
} | Export-Csv -Path "./temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have tried this below

```
$Directory = "C:\path to directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach {

    [PSCustomObject]@{                 
        Name = $_.BaseName          
    }
    
} | Export-Csv -Path "./temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The path is a string so modify the string like and other string : "./temp_" + [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".csv"

Comment: well, I am looking for three different column split from the file name  inside the a single csv file  as 
Date      Description     Amount

Comment: Use string format : [string]::Format("./temp_{0}_{1}_{2}.csv", [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"), "Hello", "123")

Comment: Why do you want to recourse the folders? Do you have pdf files in sub folders as well?

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, the below code works well. No, I don't have sub folders, all pdfs are in the same directory. You are right, I wound't need recourse in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
$Directory = '.'

(Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -File).BaseName | Select `
    @{l='Date'; e={$_.Split('_')[0]}},
    @{l='Description'; e={$_.Split('_')[1]}},
    @{l='Amount'; e={$_.Split('_')[2]}} |
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```